# Как удалить файл на диске из поля FileField/ImageField при удалении объекта?

Tags: django

```
# models.py
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, models.CASCADE)

#views.py
def index(request):
    if request.GET.get('del', False):
        Image.objects.last().delete() # но файл на диске не удаляется
        return render(request, 'index.html')
    with open('cosmos.jpg', 'rb') as f:
        im = File(f, name='real_' + request.GET.get('name', ''))
        Image.objects.create(image=im)
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

При удалении объекта сам файл на диске не удаляется. Как решить эту проблему без костылей, чтобы корректно работал `models.CASCADE`?

Comment: Периодически запускать кроном management command, который будет сверять файлы в media с записями в базе и удалять "сирот".

Comment: Вопрос в тему: Нужно ли закрывать файл из request.FILES['test.png'] ? если нет, то почему?

Comment: Не нужно. Потому что не стоит закрывать то, что не открывал. Хэндлеры открытых файлов передаёт web-сервер, он их и закроет, когда завершится обработка http-запроса.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041232

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подписаться на событие удаления объекта и в обработчике удалить картинку:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Image)
def image_model_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.image.name:
        instance.image.delete(False)
```

Можно поместить это в конце `models.py` или в `signals.py` (но тогда модуль `signals` нужно будет где-нибудь импортировать, чтобы он начал действовать — см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115097)